# Calculate sum of multiple nested rows jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My table has nested rows in which the first rows should have the sum of the values of their children.

How can I insert the sum of months into their respective quarters, and also insert the sum of the quarters into their respective years?

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcq5xhag/) with the expected result and what I have tried.

Here's another [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tqs2bdo/) with an attempt to solve this using classes.

```js
$('table thead th').each(function(i) {
  i += 1;
  calculateColumn(i);
});

function calculateColumn(index) {
  var totalColumn = 0;

  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var num = $('td', this).eq(index).text();
    if (!isNaN(num) && num.length !== 0) {
      totalColumn += parseInt(num);
    }
  });
  $('table tfoot td').eq(index).html(totalColumn.toString());
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.year-one {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.font-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Expected Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="year-one font-bold">
      <td>2022</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Total Q1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Mar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Total Q2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>May</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="font-bold">
      <td>2021</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Q1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mar</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Q2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="font-bold">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I doubt you want the total to be 54.

Comment: @mplungjan you're correct. It should be 27.

Comment: Can you give classes to the cells?

Comment: Also your   `</tfoot></tbody>` is invalid HTML

Comment: I've updated my question with another jsfiddle using classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version

I rely on `Total Q` in the first column, but a class might be safer like I did with year

```js
$('table thead th').each(function(i) {
  i += 1;
  calculateColumn(i);
});

function calculateColumn(index) {
  var totalColumn = 0;
  let totalCell;
  let yearCell;
  $('table tr').each(function(i) {
    if($(this).find("td").eq(0).hasClass('year')) yearCell = $(this).find("td").eq(index);
    if($(this).find("td").eq(0).text().includes("Total Q")) totalCell = $(this).find("td").eq(index);
    var num = $('td', this).eq(index).text();
    if (!isNaN(num) && num.length !== 0) {
      num = +num;
      yearCell.text(+yearCell.text() + num)
      totalCell.text(+totalCell.text() + num)
      totalColumn += num;
    }
  });
  $('table tfoot td').eq(index).html(totalColumn);
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 75%;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

.year-one {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.font-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="year-one font-bold">
      <td class="year">2022</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Total Q1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Mar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>Total Q2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="year-one">
      <td>May</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="font-bold">
      <td class="year">2021</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Q1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jan</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mar</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total Q2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>May</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="font-bold">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```